# Customize iOS UITextView text

Tags: ios, text, uitextview

In my iOS application i have an UITextView in which i insert some text downloaded from the web. This text is not editable/selectable by the user and it's a sort of preview of the whole text downloaded.
So, i want to show only the first two line of the text and i want to have always a vertical centered alignment. The text can also have only one line and, if there are more than two lines or there is a very long line i want to put these ".." at the end of the visible text.
I want something like this:

[image]

I hope i explained myself.

Comment: Why UITextView if not editable, not selectable ?
Why not just UILabel centered?

Comment: ok, you're right. now my text is centered vertically and horizontally. But i only see the first line of text, why?

Comment: numberOfLines is set at?

Comment: ok, i used myuilabel.numberOfLines = 2 and all works good, with the 2 points too! I'm new to iOS programming and i didn't know uilabels, answer to my question so i can give you the right answer, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it is only a preview of the entire text, you can use a UILabel instead. The UILabel will have a fixed size and it will automatically truncate the text at the end and add the "..." you want. Don't forget to specify the numberOfLines property of UILabel to be 2 and the textAlignment property to NSTextAlignmentCenter if you want it centered.